# Criar View no MySQL através do Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, view, migrations

Como posso criar uma `view` no banco de dados MySQL através das `migrations` do Laravel? Não encontrei nada na documentação.

Comment: O migrations do Laravel trabalha como um ORM?

Comment: Sim, trabalha..

Comment: não crie views no banco de dados, se seu Framework disponibilizar uma opção para fazer isso. [veja aqui um exemplo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#joins) disso na aplicação.

Comment: Algum motivo específico para não criar Views·? Qual a desvantagem?

Comment: Manutenção, você não precisaria ficar mexendo no banco de dados apenas na aplicação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existe uma forma sim e viável para criação de `Views` com [`Database Migrations`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations), mas, é uma `forma textual`:

***Comando:*** [`DB::statement`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#running-queries), *no lugar do* [`Schema::create`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#migration-structure)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Creditosativos extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        DB::statement("CREATE VIEW v_creditos_ativos AS
                        SELECT * from creditos where status = 1");
    }
    public function down()
    {
        DB::statement("DROP VIEW v_creditos_ativos");
    }
}
```

***Referencia:***

- [Eloquent and SQL Views](http://programmingarehard.com/2013/11/10/eloquent_and_views.html/)
- [Create MySQL view by migration script in Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546950/create-mysql-view-by-migration-script-in-laravel-4)

Comment: Muito obrigada!

Comment: Por nada @AmandaLima, é bom ter alguém do Laravel aqui ...